# select number from random set

Tags: python, random

when I generate a random set, I need to define each number in a different variable. I'm using `random.sample()` but the number are being repeated.

```
import random
#Generate 3 random numbers between 1 and 30
random_listOne = random.sample(range(1, 30), 3)
print(random_listOne)

valueOne = random.sample(random_listOne, 1)
valueTwo = random.sample(random_listOne, 1)
valueThree = random.sample(random_listOne, 1)

print(valueOne)
print(valueTwo)
print(valueThree)
```

just two numbers from the set are being selected, sometimes only one.

Comment: Why are you using `random.sample`? `random_listOne` is already randomized, so why not just unpack it like `valueOne, valueTwo, valueThree = random_listOne`?

Comment: When I run your code, I sometimes get all three unique values in the final result.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take [tour] and read [ask] for tips like how to write a good title. Here, the title doesn't really describe the problem, though I'm not sure how to describe it better myself. Maybe, "How can I select *unique* numbers from a random set?"

Comment: Do you need the numbers to be unique?  If so, then as @wjandrea says, `random_listOne` is already the result. you want (just do `valueOne, valueTwo, valueThree = random_listOne`).  If not, then I think your code is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

because for the part where you are picking out the random generated numbers, so `valueOne`, `valueTwo`, etc, you are picking out the generated numbers randomly, meaning that `valueOne` may have the same number as `valueTwo` since both have an equal chance at selecting one of the three generated numbers by `random.listOne`.

If you would like to avoid this, make it so that if (for example) `valueOne` has this number, then try and randomly select again for `valueTwo` and `valueThree`, etc, so that all three of these values do not end up with matching numbers.

Comment: `random.listOne`? Are you referring to `random.sample` or `random_listOne`?

Answer (score 0):

do you just want to pull out each value from the list rather than using `random.sample()` again?

```py
import random
#Generate 3 random numbers between 1 and 30
random_listOne = random.sample(range(1, 30), 3)
print(random_listOne)

valueOne = random_listOne[0]
valueTwo = random_listOne[1]
valueThree = random_listOne[2]
```